# How to populate Yes and No when applying conditions accros 3 columns only with dplyr?

Tags: r, tidyverse, multiple-conditions

I am trying to create a new column, say test, with several conditions based on 3 columns. I am tryiing to achieve this with tidyverse only. Here are my conditions:

- if I have `Yes` in one column, regardless of other categories (`No/Unknown/NA`) in the same id across columns: `previous_cabg, previous_pci, previous_ami` then assign `Yes` in test variable
- if I have `No` in all columns for the same id then assign NO for the test variable
- if I have `NO` for one column and `NA/Unknown`  in the other columns for the same id then assign with  `No` in the test variable
- if I have `Yes` in all column for the same id then assign `Yes`  in the test variable
- if I have`Yes in one column and`  NA/Unknown`for the same id in each column then assign`Yes`in test variable

This is the type of dataset I have:

```
structure(list(id = c(112139L, 43919L, 92430L, 87137L, 95417L, 
66955L, 16293L, 61396L, 25379L, 79229L, 27107L, 63243L, 50627L, 
17968L, 83015L, 96549L, 7332L, 4873L, 98131L, 93506L, 52894L, 
59327L, 85003L, 96623L, 82999L, 65769L, 67063L, 21744L, 62961L, 
2229L, 103673L, 9367L, 60215L, 74044L, 58422L, 57530L, 100399L, 
46483L, 108690L, 62017L, 46467L, 79562L, 4800L, 119158L, 103222L, 
32908L, 14491L, 30293L, 52558L, 122304L, 42281L, 1553L, 111771L, 
23087L, 30147L, 37842L, 51552L, 20148L, 28L, 7477L), previous_cabg = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
"Unknown", "Yes"), class = "factor"), previous_pci = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
"Yes", "Unknown"), class = "factor"), previous_ami = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Yes", 
"No", "Unknown"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -60L), problems = structure(list(
    row = c(34136L, 121773L, 121779L), col = c("1.01 Hospital identifier", 
    "1.01 Hospital identifier", "1.01 Hospital identifier"), 
    expected = c("value in level set", "value in level set", 
    "value in level set"), actual = c("CMH", "CMH", "CMH"), file = c("'../../data/changed/minap_2020_2021_second.csv'", 
    "'../../data/changed/minap_2020_2021_second.csv'", "'../../data/changed/minap_2020_2021_second.csv'"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And this is how it looks, but only first 10 rows, if you look in detail, I have different groups of matches across the 3 columns

```
# A tibble: 60 x 4
       id previous_cabg previous_pci previous_ami
    <int> <fct>         <fct>        <fct>       
 1 112139 No            No           No          
 2  43919 No            No           No          
 3  92430 No            Yes          Yes         
 4  87137 NA            NA           No          
 5  95417 No            No           No          
 6  66955 NA            NA           NA          
 7  16293 NA            NA           No          
 8  61396 No            Yes          Yes         
 9  25379 No            Yes          No          
10  79229 No            No           No
```

I am hoping to solve this only with tidyverse or a mix of tidyverse and r base.

This is what I have tried, yet I feel it is not so wise. I believe it is not wise, since this code will be part of automation process and if I will get other categories, than `Yes and No`, like `Unknown` as thisn appeared later in the next dataset extracts, then I wish the code will avoid all the other cases from the conditions I have given above.

```
dplyr::mutate(first_attack = 
                  dplyr::case_when(previous_cabg == 'No'  | previous_pci == 'No'  | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes',
                                   previous_cabg == 'No'  | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes',
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'No'  | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'No' ~  'Yes', 
                                   previous_cabg == 'No'  | previous_pci == 'No'  | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes',
                                   previous_cabg == 'No'  | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes',
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'No'  | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'No' ~  'Yes'
                                   
                                   # deal with the unknown category
                                   previous_cabg == 'Unknown'  | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes',
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Unknown'  | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'No' ~  'Yes', 
                                   previous_cabg == 'Unknown'  | previous_pci == 'Unknown'  | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes',
                                   previous_cabg == 'Unknown'  | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes',
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Unknown' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'Unknown' ~  'Yes', 
                                   
                                   
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' |  previous_pci == 'No'  | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~  'Yes', 
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' |  previous_pci == 'No'  | previous_ami == 'No'  ~  'Yes',
                                   previous_cabg == 'No'  |  previous_pci == 'No'  | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~  'Yes',
                                   previous_cabg == 'No'  | previous_pci == 'Yes'  | previous_ami == 'No'  ~ 'Yes', 
                                   
                                   
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' |  previous_pci == 'Unknown'   | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~  'Yes', 
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' |  previous_pci == 'Unknown'   | previous_ami == 'Unknown'   ~  'Yes',
                                   previous_cabg == 'Unknown'   |  previous_pci == 'Unknown'   | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~  'Yes',
                                   previous_cabg == 'Unknown'   | previous_pci == 'Yes'  | previous_ami == 'Unknown'   ~ 'Yes', 
                                   
                                   
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Unknown' | previous_ami == 'Unknown' ~ 'Yes', 
                                   previous_cabg == 'Unknown'  | previous_pci == 'Yes'| previous_ami == 'Unknown' ~ 'Yes', 
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'No' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                   previous_cabg == 'Unknown'  | previous_pci == 'Yes'| previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                   
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'No' | previous_ami == 'No' ~ 'Yes', 
                                   previous_cabg == 'No'  | previous_pci == 'Yes'| previous_ami == 'No' ~ 'Yes', 
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'No' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                   previous_cabg == 'No'  | previous_pci == 'Yes'| previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                   
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Unknown' | previous_ami == 'Unknown' ~ 'Yes', 
                                   previous_cabg == 'Unknown'  | previous_pci == 'Yes'| previous_ami == 'Unknown' ~ 'Yes', 
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Unknown' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                   previous_cabg == 'Unknown' | previous_pci == 'Yes'| previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                   
                                   
                                   previous_cabg == 'No'  | previous_pci == 'No'  |  previous_ami == 'No' ~ 'No', 
                                   previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Yes' |  previous_ami == 'Yes' ~'Yes'
                                   
                  ))
```

Comment: Coding all that logic is awkward, as you've found. What about a truth table that maps all combinations of the three variables to first_attack? Then you could left join the main dataset and the truth table. An NA value for first_attack would signify a new combination of the three values that you could manually review.

Comment: What you tell me is foreign to me. If you can prove it ad a post it will be more helpful?

Comment: The three conditions you listed are quite confusing. What do you mean by say "if I have Yes in all rows / or Yes and NA for the same row in each column = Yes". What do you mean by Yes in all rows? And does the "= Yes" at the end mean that the "Test" variable should be assigned "Yes"?

Comment: Yuan Yin - is the post better?

Comment: Yes it's much better! I posted a solution. I think for your future extract, you still wanna simplify your condition criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These operations are `rowwise()`, so they're not very efficient, but this solution in the `tidyverse` should cleanly achieve what you want.

Let us call your sample dataset by the name `dataset`.  Then the following workflow

```
library(tidyverse)


# ...
# Code to generate your 'dataset'.
# ...


# Define custom logic across a single row.
get_first_attack <- function(values_across_row) {
  # "Yes" overrides all other values.
  if(isTRUE(any(values_across_row == "Yes"))){
    return("Yes")
  }
  # "No" overrides all missing values: 'NA' and "Unknown".
  else if(isTRUE(any(values_across_row == "No"))) {
    return("No")
  }
  # "Unknown" overrides all other missing values: 'NA'.
  else if(isTRUE(any(values_across_row == "Unknown"))) {
    return("Unknown")
  }
  # All values are missing: 'NA'.
  else {
    return(as.character(NA))
  }
}


dataset %>%
  # Examine row by row.
  dplyr::rowwise() %>%
  # Compare values across each row according to the logic in 'get_first_attack()'.
  dplyr::mutate(first_attack = get_first_attack(across(previous_cabg:previous_ami))) %>%
  # Exit row-wise approach, to restore efficiency.
  dplyr::ungroup() %>%
  # Factor 'first_attack' exactly like its neighboring column.
  dplyr::mutate(first_attack = factor(first_attack, levels = levels(previous_ami)))
```

should give you these results

```
# A tibble: 60 x 5
       id previous_cabg previous_pci previous_ami first_attack
    <int> <fct>         <fct>        <fct>        <fct>       
 1 112139 No            No           No           No          
 2  43919 No            No           No           No          
 3  92430 No            Yes          Yes          Yes         
 4  87137 NA            NA           No           No          
 5  95417 No            No           No           No          
 6  66955 NA            NA           NA           NA          
 7  16293 NA            NA           No           No          
 8  61396 No            Yes          Yes          Yes         
 9  25379 No            Yes          No           Yes         
10  79229 No            No           No           No          
# ... with 50 more rows
```

where the `first_attack` column is fittingly defined as a `factor` with three levels: `"Yes"`, `"No"`, and `"Unknown"`.

Comment: This solution is such an elegant one. I can even pass get_first_attack function with purrr::map if I have all my variables in a list, keeping only the id's as a columns. This is wow!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help, @GaB!

Comment: and you are new as well. I bet you'll get top in stackoverflow if you help around!! Thanks!

Comment: You're too kind, @GaB!  And for the record, you were wise to think of `dplyr::case_when()`.  It's almost always the right (most efficient) call, in situations where you have to apply logical conditions to several columns in a dataset.  This situation was just a little more complex in how the information was structured...so I took extra steps to simplify the logic with `get_first_attack()`.  Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 2):

So in summary, your condition is:

- **For each row, if any column is 'Yes', output 'Yes'**
- **For each row, if all column is NA, output NA**
- **For each row, if all column is 'Unknown', output 'Unknown'**
- **Otherwise output 'No'**

If this is the case, you can do:

```
# Convert your data structure into a data.frame
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)

# Remove id col
id <- dat$id
dat <- subset(dat, select = -c(id))

# For each row, check if there is a 'Yes' under any column. If so, return 'Yes'; otherwise return 'No'
output <- apply(dat, 1, function(x) ifelse('Yes' %in% x, 'Yes', 'No'))

# For each row, check if NA under all column. If so, return TRUE; otherwise return FALSE.
isNA <- apply(dat, 1, function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), TRUE, FALSE))

# Now merge output and isNA
output[isNA] <- NA

# For each row, check if 'Unknown' under all column. If so, return TRUE; otherwise return FALSE.
isUK <- apply(dat, 1, function(x) ifelse(all('Unknown' == x), TRUE, FALSE))

# Now merge output and isUK
output[isUK] <- 'Unknown'

# Append the output character vector to a new col of the data frame
dat$id <- id
dat$test <- output
```

Comment: thank you. Yet, when I have applied it, when I have NA's, I get No

Comment: Oops haha. So what do you expect when you have NA? Do you mean NA under all 3 columns?

Comment: yes, I do expect NA for all 3 columns. Also, just to make you aware,in my dataset I have other variables, and I am hoping the solution to take into account all the other variables.  If there is a solution with tidyverse, that will be better. Thank you a lot for your effort. Moreover, I have the Unknown as a category as well.

Comment: yes, but you see, if it has NA in one column, Yes in another and Unknown in the third, then I want this to be Yes. As in my code above I do indeed specify that with case_when and even the first point. Dang man :)  Although case_when isn't the right function to be used in this case.

Comment: again, the solution given doesn't work. I have a case where I have Yes, Unknown, NA, and the output is Unknown with your solutions. Yet, it should be Yes according to my post. Pam, Pam

Comment: There was a bug. The updated code is posted. I'm not sure if you want all 'Unknown' entry to return 'Unknown', but I coded that in. If you don't need that, you can just delete the corresponding 2 lines.

Comment: Yuan Yin, thank you so much for your effort. I am very pleased already with the above asnwer as it is a blend of base R and tidyverse.

Comment: Well my code is vectorized so it should be faster than looping and applying function row by row. But of course, if you prefer tidyverse I can't think of a way to vectorize it. And if you are working with small dataset, time is not a problem. All the best.

Comment: but isn't tidyverse, which was a requirement mentioned within my post. Check tidyverse library, it is really powerful library. You'll love it!

Comment: @GaB In all fairness to [@YuanYin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7922928), a `base` solution is often preferable to having dependencies — even on packages as useful as `tidyverse` — because `base` functionality is more portable and supremely stable.  As long as the `base` solution is comparably clean and efficient — not to mention understandable and extensible — it's often the better approach. In this case, however, the `base` solution sacrifices cleanliness and extensibility to achieve its efficiency.

Comment: @Greg indeed, I am not denying it. It is just what you’ve said in the last phrase. Additionally, your code will allow me to get into a list column and retrieve the variable with purrr::map

Comment: @GaB I'm glad it ended up being so useful for you!