# Why do I not get my desired category in the new columns with case_when, in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, case-when, multiple-conditions

I am trying to create a new column, first_attack, with several conditions based on 3 columns. I am trying to achieve this with tidyverse only. Here are my conditions:

- if I have `Yes` in one column, regardless of other categories (`No/Unknown/NA`) in the same id across columns: `previous_cabg, previous_pci, previous_ami` then assign `Yes` in test variable
- if I have `No` in all columns for the same id then assign NO for the test variable
- if I have `NO` for one column and `NA/Unknown`  in the other columns for the same id then assign with  `No` in the test variable
- if I have `Yes` in all column for the same id then assign `Yes`  in the test variable
- if I have`Yes in one column and`  NA/Unknown`for the same id in each column then assign`Yes`in test variable

This is the type of dataset I have:

```
structure(list(id = c(112139L, 43919L, 92430L, 87137L, 95417L, 
66955L, 16293L, 61396L, 25379L, 79229L, 27107L, 63243L, 50627L, 
17968L, 83015L, 96549L, 7332L, 4873L, 98131L, 93506L, 52894L, 
59327L, 85003L, 96623L, 82999L, 65769L, 67063L, 21744L, 62961L, 
2229L, 103673L, 9367L, 60215L, 74044L, 58422L, 57530L, 100399L, 
46483L, 108690L, 62017L, 46467L, 79562L, 4800L, 119158L, 103222L, 
32908L, 14491L, 30293L, 52558L, 122304L, 42281L, 1553L, 111771L, 
23087L, 30147L, 37842L, 51552L, 20148L, 28L, 7477L), previous_cabg = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
"Unknown", "Yes"), class = "factor"), previous_pci = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
"Yes", "Unknown"), class = "factor"), previous_ami = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Yes", 
"No", "Unknown"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -60L), problems = structure(list(
    row = c(34136L, 121773L, 121779L), col = c("1.01 Hospital identifier", 
    "1.01 Hospital identifier", "1.01 Hospital identifier"), 
    expected = c("value in level set", "value in level set", 
    "value in level set"), actual = c("CMH", "CMH", "CMH"), file = c("'../../data/changed/minap_2020_2021_second.csv'", 
    "'../../data/changed/minap_2020_2021_second.csv'", "'../../data/changed/minap_2020_2021_second.csv'"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I thought the best is to use case_when. Thus, I oddly I proceeded with it. This is the code.

```
  test_first_attack <- sample_n %>%
      dplyr::mutate(first_attack = 
                      dplyr::case_when(  
                                        previous_cabg == 'No'  | previous_pci == 'No'  | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes',
                                        previous_cabg == 'No'  | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes',
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'No'  | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'No' ~  'Yes', 
                                        previous_cabg == 'No'  | previous_pci == 'No'  | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes',
                                        previous_cabg == 'No'  | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes',
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'No'  | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'No' ~  'Yes',
                                        
                                        # deal with the unknown category
                                        previous_cabg == 'Unknown'  | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes',
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Unknown'  | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'Unknown' ~  'Yes', 
                                        previous_cabg == 'Unknown'  | previous_pci == 'Unknown'  | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes',
                                        previous_cabg == 'Unknown'  | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes',
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Unknown' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'Unknown' ~  'Yes', 
                                        
                                        
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' |  previous_pci == 'No'  | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~  'Yes', 
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' |  previous_pci == 'No'  | previous_ami == 'No'  ~  'Yes',
                                        previous_cabg == 'No'  |  previous_pci == 'No'  | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~  'Yes',
                                        previous_cabg == 'No'  | previous_pci == 'Yes'  | previous_ami == 'No'  ~ 'Yes', 
                                        
                                        
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' |  previous_pci == 'Unknown'   | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~  'Yes', 
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' |  previous_pci == 'Unknown'   | previous_ami == 'Unknown'   ~  'Yes',
                                        previous_cabg == 'Unknown'   |  previous_pci == 'Unknown'   | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~  'Yes',
                                        previous_cabg == 'Unknown'   | previous_pci == 'Yes'  | previous_ami == 'Unknown'   ~ 'Yes', 
                                        
                                        
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Unknown' | previous_ami == 'Unknown' ~ 'Yes', 
                                        previous_cabg == 'Unknown'  | previous_pci == 'Yes'| previous_ami == 'Unknown' ~ 'Yes', 
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'No' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                        previous_cabg == 'Unknown'  | previous_pci == 'Yes'| previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                        
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'No' | previous_ami == 'No' ~ 'Yes', 
                                        previous_cabg == 'No'  | previous_pci == 'Yes'| previous_ami == 'No' ~ 'Yes', 
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'No' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                        previous_cabg == 'No'  | previous_pci == 'Yes'| previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                        
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Unknown' | previous_ami == 'Unknown' ~ 'Yes', 
                                        previous_cabg == 'Unknown'  | previous_pci == 'Yes'| previous_ami == 'Unknown' ~ 'Yes', 
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Unknown' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                        previous_cabg == 'Unknown' | previous_pci == 'Yes'| previous_ami == 'Yes' ~ 'Yes', 
                                        previous_cabg == 'No'  | previous_pci == 'No'  |  previous_ami == 'No' ~ 'No',
                                        previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Yes' |  previous_ami == 'Yes' ~'Yes'
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                      ))
```

This is the output.

```
 test_first_attack <-  structure(list(id = c(112139L, 43919L, 92430L, 87137L, 95417L, 
    66955L, 16293L, 61396L, 25379L, 79229L, 27107L, 63243L, 50627L, 
    17968L, 83015L, 96549L, 7332L, 4873L, 98131L, 93506L, 52894L, 
    59327L, 85003L, 96623L, 82999L, 65769L, 67063L, 21744L, 62961L, 
    2229L, 103673L, 9367L, 60215L, 74044L, 58422L, 57530L, 100399L, 
    46483L, 108690L, 62017L, 46467L, 79562L, 4800L, 119158L, 103222L, 
    32908L, 14491L, 30293L, 52558L, 122304L, 42281L, 1553L, 111771L, 
    23087L, 30147L, 37842L, 51552L, 20148L, 28L, 7477L), previous_cabg = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Unknown", "Yes"), class = "factor"), previous_pci = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes", "Unknown"), class = "factor"), previous_ami = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Yes", 
    "No", "Unknown"), class = "factor"), first_attack = c("Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", NA, "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", NA, "Yes", "Yes", 
    NA, "Yes", NA, "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", NA, "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", NA, "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", NA, "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -60L), problems = structure(list(row = c(34136L, 
    121773L, 121779L), col = c("1.01 Hospital identifier", "1.01 Hospital identifier", 
    "1.01 Hospital identifier"), expected = c("value in level set", 
    "value in level set", "value in level set"), actual = c("CMH", 
    "CMH", "CMH"), file = c("'../../data/changed/minap_2020_2021_second.csv'", 
    "'../../data/changed/minap_2020_2021_second.csv'", "'../../data/changed/minap_2020_2021_second.csv'"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

As you can see, I get 'Yes' as output for the columns with id rows with NO across all the columns. Let alone taking into consideration more complex conditions like 'Unknown\NA\Yes' or other conditions.

Why I cannot get my desired output? Is there another way to achieve it with tidyverse only?

Comment: I think you need some `&`s in your logic, you can't do it with only `|`.

Comment: How is this different from the question you posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68459223/2835261)?

Comment: the answer given isn't tidyverse. Additionally, here I ask why yet in the other one I ask How. Which is very different question on the same problem. You probably right to charge me on this.

Comment: You can probably collapse a lot of these into a single line. For example, if the result should be "Yes" when at least one of the three test columns is "Yes" (your first condition in the bullet points), then you can cover most of the specific cases (including cases where one or two of the test columns is "Unknown") with: `previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~  'Yes'`. This would cover almost all of the individual cases in your example code.

Comment: Andrew Gustar - would you please  put it as a post and explain the difference between | and &, and || ? Because  as I have read, there are indeed differences.

Comment: eipi, I want the output to be No as well, your solution give me the output as Yes even for the No for all categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is:

```
case_when(
    previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~  'Yes',
    previous_cabg == 'No' | previous_pci == 'No' | previous_ami == 'No' ~  'No',
    TRUE ~ "Unknown/NA"
)
```

The first line will result in a "Yes" for every row where at least one of the three test columns is "Yes". The rows that satisfy the first line of the `case_when` will not be tested for any subsequent conditions.

Of the remaining rows, the second line will result in a "No" where any of the three test columns is "No". The rows that meet the second line of the `case_when` will not be tested for any subsequent conditions.

The last line assigns "Unknown/NA" to all remaining rows, which should be only those rows that don't have any "Yes" or "No" values in the three test columns.

For completeness, here's a full reproducible example using your sample data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

test_first_attack = structure(list(id = c(112139L, 43919L, 92430L, 87137L, 95417L, 
                                          66955L, 16293L, 61396L, 25379L, 79229L, 27107L, 63243L, 50627L, 
                                          17968L, 83015L, 96549L, 7332L, 4873L, 98131L, 93506L, 52894L, 
                                          59327L, 85003L, 96623L, 82999L, 65769L, 67063L, 21744L, 62961L, 
                                          2229L, 103673L, 9367L, 60215L, 74044L, 58422L, 57530L, 100399L, 
                                          46483L, 108690L, 62017L, 46467L, 79562L, 4800L, 119158L, 103222L, 
                                          32908L, 14491L, 30293L, 52558L, 122304L, 42281L, 1553L, 111771L, 
                                          23087L, 30147L, 37842L, 51552L, 20148L, 28L, 7477L), previous_cabg = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                           1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                           1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                           1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
                                                                                                                                                                                   "Unknown", "Yes"), class = "factor"), previous_pci = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "Yes", "Unknown"), class = "factor"), previous_ami = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1L, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Yes", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "No", "Unknown"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -60L), problems = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       row = c(34136L, 121773L, 121779L), col = c("1.01 Hospital identifier", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "1.01 Hospital identifier", "1.01 Hospital identifier"), 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       expected = c("value in level set", "value in level set", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "value in level set"), actual = c("CMH", "CMH", "CMH"), file = c("'../../data/changed/minap_2020_2021_second.csv'", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "'../../data/changed/minap_2020_2021_second.csv'", "'../../data/changed/minap_2020_2021_second.csv'"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



test_first_attack = test_first_attack %>% 
  mutate(first_attack = case_when(
    previous_cabg == 'Yes' | previous_pci == 'Yes' | previous_ami == 'Yes' ~  'Yes',
    previous_cabg == 'No' | previous_pci == 'No' | previous_ami == 'No' ~  'No',
    TRUE ~ "Unknown/NA"
  ))

test_first_attack
#> # A tibble: 60 x 5
#>        id previous_cabg previous_pci previous_ami first_attack
#>     <int> <fct>         <fct>        <fct>        <chr>       
#>  1 112139 No            No           No           No          
#>  2  43919 No            No           No           No          
#>  3  92430 No            Yes          Yes          Yes         
#>  4  87137 <NA>          <NA>         No           No          
#>  5  95417 No            No           No           No          
#>  6  66955 <NA>          <NA>         <NA>         Unknown/NA  
#>  7  16293 <NA>          <NA>         No           No          
#>  8  61396 No            Yes          Yes          Yes         
#>  9  25379 No            Yes          No           Yes         
#> 10  79229 No            No           No           No          
#> # … with 50 more rows
```

Comment: eipi10 - I got    Error: Case 1 (`.`) must be a two-sided formula, not a `tbl_df/tbl/data.frame` object. But yours seems to be closer to my answer? I may need to see the output to let you know I am getting the right answer

Comment: solved it with a mutate and defined with as a variable. It worked really nice! Thank you eipi10

Answer (score 0):

What if you try "ifelse"?

```
test <- test %>% mutate(first_attack = ifelse(previous_cabg == "Yes" | previous_pci == "Yes" | previous_ami == "Yes", "Yes", "No"))
```

Comment: Bloxx, it doesn't work at all. Becasue I have Unknown category as well. ifelse is for 2 categories. :)

Comment: You can stack more ifelse statements together... In the third argument you can put new ifelse with new conditions...

Comment: did you try it? I believe you did not? :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have two desired outputs: Yes & No? If in any is Yes THAN Yes, OTHERWISE NO.

Comment: nope, that isn't true. Look at the solution given.

Comment: you put down 5 condition statements in your question. All of them end with Yes or No as the desired output. Can you point to which of your condition statement instruct different output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235117/discussion-between-bloxx-and-gab).